# Улучшение качества звукозаписи в BASS.NET

Tags: c#, bass.net

Имеет ли BASS.NET библиотека возможности улучшения качества звукозаписи (устранение шумов и щелчков)?

Comment: Напрямую нет, но она предоставляет возможность разложения сигнала в спектр частот: http://www.bass.radio42.com/help/html/a13cfef0-1056-bb94-81c4-a4fdf21bd463.htm Пользуясь спектром можно применить какие-то фильтры (например, в самом простом случае - отсечь все амплитуды ниже определенного значения).

Comment: Да. Это тоже подойдёт) Шумовой порог можно организовать.. Функции обратного преобразования тоже есть?

Comment: Вроде нет. Но обратное должно легко считаться по формулам. Просто сумма синусоид.